# Save items to different childs in firebase

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I save data to different childs in a firebase?

I push items to a firebase using onclick function and if/else statements for creating different categories.


**Example**

Button1 click -> push data from inputform to child1 in firebase,

Button2 click -> push data from inputform to child2 in firebase....

**Problem**

The item is pushed to one child only (e.g. ref0).
Everytime I push further items into the firebase, there appended to the ref0 child and not assigned to a new child (e.g. ref1).

Unfortunately I can´t find specific information for solving this issue.
Would be great if you can support me.
Check my Code for more specific information.

```js
//create firebase reference
var dbRef = new Firebase('https://firebaseurl.firebaseio.com/');
var ref0 = dbRef.child('ref0');
var ref1 = dbRef.child('ref1');
var ref2 = dbRef.child('ref2');
var ref3 = dbRef.child('ref3');

var showAllRefs = ref0, ref1, ref2, ref3;

//load all contacts (limited to last 5 items)
showAllRefs.limitToLast(5).on("child_added", function(snap) {
  snap.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
  var key = childSnapshot.key();
  var childData = childSnapshot.val();

  //create divs from database-elements
  var card = document.createElement('div');
  card.setAttribute('class', 'linkprev');
  $('#content').prepend($(card));
  
  var cardtitle = document.createElement('div');
  cardtitle.setAttribute('class', 'cardtitle');
  cardtitle.innerHTML = childData;
  card.appendChild(cardtitle);
  });
  $(document).ready(function(){
  document.guteUrls.execute('linkprev');
});
});

//save contact
  //save in database contacts
  var elements = $('.f');
  //console.log(elements);


//save items to firebase(childs)
  var buttonPressed = function( event ) {  
    event.preventDefault();
      
    //url validation from inputfield using Regex
    var valpattern = new RegExp('^(http|https)://'+ // protocol
    '((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.?)+[a-z]{2,}|'+ // domain name
    '((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))'+ // OR ip (v4) address
    '(\\:\\d+)?(\\/[-a-z\\d%_.~+]*)*'+ // port and path
    '(\\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?'+ // query string
    '(\\#[-a-z\\d_]*)?$','i'); // fragment locator
    var valselect = document.getElementById('url');
    var val = valpattern.test(valselect.value);
    
    //save in database to different childs on buttonclick
    if(val && document.querySelector(".f1")){ref0.push({name: document.querySelector('#url').value})
      contactForm.reset();}
    else if(val && document.querySelector(".g1")){ref1.push({name: document.querySelector('#url').value})
      contactForm.reset();}
    else if(val && document.querySelector(".h1")){ref2.push({name: document.querySelector('#url').value})
      contactForm.reset();}
    else if(val && document.querySelector(".i1")){ref3.push({name: document.querySelector('#url').value})
      contactForm.reset();}
    else {
    alert('Oops');}
};

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {elements[i].addEventListener("click", buttonPressed, false);}
```

Thanks in advance

Ben

Comment: Are you trying to push data to these 4 root refs (ref0, ref1, ref2, ref3) as children or just assign 1 value to each of these root references?

Comment: Yes, I try to add children to the refs via push method.